# jboss 7 standalone: exclude folder from deploying

Tags: deployment, jboss7.x

In my deployment, I have folder with  thousands of Wave files.It causes very long delay when deploying the project. 
how can I tell Jboss  exclude this folder in deployment process?

I am using JAS 7, in Standalone mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the folder using # character

For example:

```
test.war
    #dontDeployThis
        file1.wave
        ...
        ...
    WEB-INF
    index.html
    ...
```

jboss won't deploy dontDeployThis folder

Hope it helps!